# redmi 5a: custom rom freezes

Tags: custom-roms, bluetooth, system-freeze, redmi

my rom freezes a few seconds after it booted up, the screen gets black, then it turns off and there is nothing i can do but reboot. before it freezes it says com.android.bluetooth stopped. perhaps it has something 2 do with it.

im on: crDroidAndroid-8.1-20180926-riva-v4.6.1

recovery: OrangeFox-R8.3-riva

i tried several roms, recoveries and the inferno kernel but same problem. no problem with stock rom.

i got some logs:

logcat (not the complete log): [logcat](https://pastebin.com/if737ftV)

dmesg: [kernel boot log](https://pastebin.com/PaZm7Lsr)

the new last_kmsg are empty but i have old ones. i can post them if u think they r important. and i have a tombstone log for bluetooth. buts its 2 big 2 post at pastebin ;D i can do it if its important.

sum1 has a hint for me?

cheers

Comment: This should be reported to the respective ROM threads instead.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-redmi-5a/development, here you have other rom's available for your device. select official one's which have more number of posts and discussions (bcz the developer will be active by solving bugs reported by users)

Comment: did u read that this problem is not related to one custom rom? this problem occurs on every custom rom i tried. so its not a rom only problem. i could report it to every custom rom thread ;D i wont do this and i asked at the redmi 5a thread. they couldnt help me yet so i try it here ;>

Comment: i forgot 2 mention: it once worked. but then i flashed a newer version of crdroid. since then no custom rom works :/ i thought it could b a hardware issue but  the stock rom works... dunno

Comment: @morturio it is definitely an issue related to the custom ROM('s) source code. Based on your logs it looks like the vendor blobs need to be updated more details would confirm it. Have all the roms you tried been higher then your devices base firmware of android 7.1.2 or all been android 8.x. Have you tried a custom rom of android version 7.1.2 and had bluetooth issue. Most likely the ROM's you tried all use the same proprietary vendor source in their manifest.

Comment: who can update them? (how) can i give more details? all roms i tried were 8.x oder 9.x. i will try 7.1.2 now (viper os). i cant tell for sure that the bluetooth issue always appeared. sometimes the rom didnt/does not even boot up completely. yeah i thought it maybe has sumthing to do with the vendor thing. i once wiped internal storage and formatted data. perhaps a newer twrp version caused the incompatibility. but the combination which worked once does not work anymore :( thx so far @ all

Comment: so i just installed viper os 7.1.2 and it works fine :o

Comment: so what can i do that android 8 und 9 is working?

Comment: problem solved: did a full restore of my full nandroid backupt with twrp. no everythinks works fine ;> dunno what the prob was. never mind